# Passar função pelo two way data bind

Tags: javascript, angular

Queria saber se é possível passar uma função por meio do *two way data bind* do angular. 
Vou tentar explicar, tenho um componente com 3 botões e gostaria de usá-los em várias parte do meu projeto. 
Queria pode passar as funções para os botões executarem, tentarei dar um exemplo.

componente onde quero implementar meu botões:

```
<div>
  <component-btns [(botao1)]="funcao1" [(botao2)]="funcao2" [(botao3)]="funcao3"><component-btns>
</div>
```

Essas funções serão recebidas no meu `component-btns` e referenciadas aos botões no meu html.

Se eu executar as funções e pedir um `console.log(this)` o que será impresso é o `this` do meu `component-btns` e não o `this` que usei para implementar e passar as funções para meu `component-btns`.

É bem confuso o que quero fazer, queria saber se é possível fazer algo assim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer algo assim: dentro do seu *component-btns* você vai definir alguns *Outputs*

```
@Component({
   selector: 'component-btns',
   templateUrl: 'component-btns.component.html'
})
export class ComponentBtns {
    @Output('botao1')
    botao1Event: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    @Output('botao2)
    botao2Event: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    @Output('botao3')
    botao3Event: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    botao1Click() {
        this.botao1Event.emit();
    }

    botao2Click() {
        this.botao2Event.emit();
    }

    botao3Click() {
        this.botao3Event.emit();
    }
}
```

Você pode ler sobre os *EventEmitter* [aqui](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter)

Tendo isso montado, no template que você quiser utilizar o *component-btns* você pode utilizar *event binding* nos *Output* que você definiu. Exemplo:

```
<component-btns (botao1)="funcaoBotao1()" (botao2)="funcaoBotao2()" (botao3)="funcaoBotao3()"><component-btns>
```

Dessa maneira, quando o botão for clicado, ele executará a função de dentro do *ComponentBtns* que emitirá um evento, no qual o seu componente pai estará ouvindo e respondendo.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, eu estava tentando fazer de uma maneira completamente diferente, você salvou meu dia rsrs, muito obrigado

Comment: Disponha, a documentação do Angular ajuda bastante, quando puder dê uma lida, tem bastante coisa interessante.